# How to display firstname in UILabel?I am developing IOS app with Firebase and Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase

I am practicing IOS app using Firebase and Swift.

This is an basic app where a user logs in with username and password. User can Signup, login, and logout. For this I have created 3 viewcontrollers.One for userlogin, 2nd to signup, and third to display user's firstname and picture.

I have created a viewcontroller "loginPageViewController" to display user's firstname and picture. I am trying to display firstname in "userFirstName" label. But I am unable to do. Error message is attached in screenshot.

Supplements:

[Error is occured here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGIEv.png)

[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EYWp.png)

Swift Code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class loginPageViewController: ViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var userFirstName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var userImage: UIImageView!

let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let userID = (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!

    ref.child("expatsappmembers").child(userID).observeSingleEventOfType(
        .Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            let firstName = snapshot.value!["firstName"] as! String
            self.userFirstName.text = firstName
    })
}

@IBAction func LogoutButtoninLoginPage(sender: AnyObject) {

    if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser != nil{ //there is a user signed in

        do{

        try FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()

            if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser == nil{

                let loginVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("InitialView") as? ViewController

                self.presentViewController(loginVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }       

        }catch let signOutError as NSError{
        print ("Erros signing out: %@", signOutError)
        }

    }   
}
```

}
 "
Any suggestions will be a great help for me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The error means you have a `nil` in your `userID`.

Comment: Why I am getting nil? in userID. Am i giving correct values for child?please help.

Comment: I'm nut familiar with Firebase, but where did you make the network request to have Firevase return the data? if you didn't, then that's why `userID` is `nil`.  Also, you declared `userID` twice, one at the beginning, one in `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: i have imported " import Firebase  import FirebaseAuth". I also made all the steps to interact with Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Before the user have logged in the `FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid` is nil. The problem is that you force unwrap it (`!`).
You should first check that the user is logged in, and only then continue with your logic.

I would start with this:

```
if let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid  {
    ref.child("expatsappmembers").child(userID).observeSingleEventOfType(
        .Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            if let firstName = snapshot.value?["firstName"] as? String {
                self.userFirstName.text = firstName
            }
    })
}
```

Comment: override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        
        if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser != nil {
        
            if let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {
        
        ref.child("expatsappmembers").child(userID).observeSingleEventOfType(
            .Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
                 let firstName = snapshot.value!["firstName"] as! String
                self.userFirstName.text = firstName
                
                
        })
        }
        }

Comment: why I am getting nil in UserID. Am I giving correct values in child

Comment: ref.child("expatsappmembers").child(userID).observeSingleEventOfType

Comment: Nil userID is only because the user is signed out, or timing issue, because it can take few seconds for it to update after successful login.